# Fuzzy sets/logic free ebooks

Tags: book-recommendation, fuzzy-logic, fuzzy-set

I need to find a free e-book about fuzzy sets/logic. But there are some requirements: this book must be published after 2010 and its size must be about 250. I have a task at my university to translate some book connected with fuzzy sets/logic and it would be good if the book will be not so difficult, like for beginners - but it is optional.
Thanks

Comment: If you are going to invest your personal time in translating as many as 250 pages (2 months full-time?) then surely you can afford to pay for a regular copy?

Comment: @Justpassingby The task is not billable, and it is better to have a copy that I can edit. But except the "free" requrement, what book can you advice?

Comment: I just meant that even for a non-billable task, the opportunity cost to yourself is tremendous. Compared to that, the price of a single e-book represents only a small amount of working time even in the lowest-paid student jobs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following book fits the date and size requirements: B. Bede, "Mathematics of Fuzzy Sets and Fuzzy Logic," Springer 2013.